# Index of substring in SQLite3?

Tags: string, sqlite, substring

What's the most straightforward way of finidng the index of a substring in a varchar column?  `charindex` doesn't exist in the stock version of SQLite3 -- which is still a little surprising to me.

Specifically, I have a column with values like `010000`, `011000`, `010110`, etc.  I want to find the index of the first occurence of `11`.  For the examples I gave, I would expect something like `NULL` (or `-1`), `1`, and `3`.

I have a hacked together idea that uses `length` and `ltrim`, but it seems like a lot of work for something I need to do several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you've found the only answer that currently works. SQLite does not have a charindex equivalent function. You an make your own with length and trim, but nothing is built in:(

Comment: That's so strange...  Even something that's just syntactic sugar (but built in) would be fine.  I wonder what the rationale of *not* including something like `charindex` is...

Answer (score 12):

This is now possible using the builtin `instr` function.

```
sqlite> select instr(010000,11);
0
sqlite> select instr(011000,11);
1
sqlite> select instr(010110,11);
3
```

Comment: sqlite 3.7.6 and below does not include this function :(