# Split FirstName and LastName in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a table in sqlite db called [tblbook] with a column [authors]. What I am trying to do in the sql is to split the author values to firstname and the lastname and sort it on lastname. I did find this great code:

```
 SELECT substr(BookAuthor, 1, NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ', BookAuthor) - 1, -1)) AS [FirstName],
   substr(BookAuthor, CHARINDEX(' ', BookAuthor) + 1, LEN(BookAuthor)) AS [LastName]
 FROM tblBook where _id=3
```

It works perfectly on MSSQL but sqlite doesn't have the charindex function hence it fails.

Could anyone please be kind and advise me what should be the best approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality is missing from SQLite:

- http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html
- [Index of substring in SQLite3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188811/index-of-substring-in-sqlite3)

Maybe you can feed your custom string position function to SQLite using http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html

But if you really need it, there is a complex, ineffective workaround:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/e03a4/3

1: create a numbers table/view

2: join authors to numbers table, and choose the MIN position of the space

3: now you can split the names

```
SELECT
  substr( name, 1, pos-1) AS first_name,
  substr( name,    pos+1) AS last_name
FROM (
      SELECT
        author.name,
        numbers.x AS pos
      FROM       author
      INNER JOIN numbers
      WHERE substr( author.name, numbers.x, 1) = ' '
      GROUP BY author.name
     ) AS a
ORDER BY last_name;
```

Comment: Thank you biziclop for your explanation. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Maybe the reason they don't include string search is that they didn't want to deal with different encodings, utf/8/16/666, etc, because that would blow up the sqlite code size.

Answer (score 35):

Another way (a little shorter) to write this would be

```
SELECT 
  substr(BookAuthor, 1, instr(BookAuthor, ' ') - 1) AS first_name,
  substr(BookAuthor,    instr(BookAuthor, ' ') + 1) AS last_name
FROM tblBook where id=3
ORDER BY last_name
```

This would apply for version 3.7.15 and beyond.

Comment: When the string has no separator, this puts the whole string in column last_name. I added `case when instr(BookAuthor, ' ')` before both lines to put it in first_name instead.

Comment: But in case there is only a first name, this doesn't sort properly. For example, `substr(BookAuthor, 1, instr(BookAuthor, ' ') - 1) ` gives null value for `Book Author=AShley` only with first name.