# Sqlite: Iterating through substrings of a string field

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, for-loop, substring

I have a field which contains a string of numbers

```
 "2002 2005 2001 2006 2008 2344"
```

It is preferred that we assume the spaces are the splits, else failing that, that they are 4 characters long each.

I can select a substring:

```
SELECT substr(years,1,4)  FROM TABLE
```

But have no idea how to check each one. I am trying to find the row that contains the number closest to 0.

and I can `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Meh, If the field in question is short enough that the retrieval and maths operation need not be done in the DB layer (i.e. it won't result in a slow down) I would just pull this out of the database with a Cursor and use ````StringUtils#split(String)```` on it. From there I would use the returned ````String[]````, throw it into a Collections#sort() method and retrieve the lowest value.

Comment: @OceanLife Unfortunately there are too many rows, and it takes 3+ seconds just to draw back all the rows it needs to check from (ignoring computation then done on it). Where as an sql statement to get one row would be a lot faster (instant). - It currently runs in java code.

Comment: Bummer. Sounds like quite the problem from a quick Google. This question had some ideas but they all looked u.g.l.y. The idea of populating a temporary table's column with the row value and sorting could work. Not sure of the overhead of clearing it down between each row though.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155886/split-firstname-and-lastname-in-sqllite

Comment: How many numbers are in the string?  What is the maximum number?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It varies. Could be 1, could be 20. And each row will vary :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks UGLY but it selects all you need in one SQLlite statement. Also you can do some optimization if assume dates are in the current interval say 1900..2100. In this case you can cut first 2 selects B,C (B: 1 union 2) (C: 9 union 0 union 1)

```
 select years2,years from 
    (
    select i1||i2||i3||i4  as years2 from (select '0' as i1 
                   union all 
                   select '1' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '2' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '3' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '4' as i1 
                   union all 
                   select '5' as i1 
                   union all 
                   select '6' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '7' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '8' as i1
                   union all 
                   select '9' as i1) B, 
    (select '0' as i2 
                   union all 
                   select '1' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '2' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '3' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '4' as i2 
                   union all 
                   select '5' as i2 
                   union all 
                   select '6' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '7' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '8' as i2
                   union all 
                   select '9' as i2) C,
    (select '0' as i3 
                   union all 
                   select '1' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '2' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '3' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '4' as i3 
                   union all 
                   select '5' as i3 
                   union all 
                   select '6' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '7' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '8' as i3
                   union all 
                   select '9' as i3) D,
                  (select '0' as i4 
                   union all 
                   select '1' as i4
                   union all 
                   select '2' as i4
                   union all 
                   select '3' as i4 
                   union all 
                   select '4' as i4 
                   union all 
                   select '5' as i4 
                   union all 
                   select '6' as i4
                   union all 
                   select '7' as i4
                   union all 
                   select '8' as i4
                   union all 
                   select '9' as i4) E
    ) YearsAll

   left join YearsTable on (YearsTable.years like '%'||YearsAll.years2||'%')

    where YearsTable.years is not null

    order by years2 limit 1
```

Comment: Ok I follow most of it, except the left join. Should the % not be around the yearsTable.years? A good effort. I might give it a try. +1

Comment: YearsTable.years is your long strings ""2002 2005 2001 2006 2008 2344". YearsAll contains all years from 0000 to 9999. So for one example record this condition looks like: ' 2002 2005 2001 2006 2008 2344 ' like ' %2002% '. So it is true if 2002 is in this string. Also I've added first and last spaces ' ' to years as soon condition is ' %year% '

Comment: Fixed join condition. There is no need to uses additional spaces in condition because all digits have fixed (4 chars) length and separated by spaces

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common table expression to split out the year in the years string and then get the year closest to 0.

```
WITH split_years(year, years) AS (
    values(0, '2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006'||' ')
    UNION ALL SELECT
    cast(substr(years, 0, instr(years, ' ')) as int),
    substr(years, instr(years, ' ')+1)
    FROM split WHERE length(years)
) SELECT year FROM split_years WHERE year>0 ORDER BY year LIMIT 1;
```

Output is:

```
2001
```