# How to write a select query for splitting, extracting in sqlite db?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, parsing, select, split

I have a table in some sqlite db with a column 'VAL'.

### schema

```
CREATE TABLE TB_XXX ( VAL TEXT );
```

### original data example

If I execute the query `SELECT * FROM TB_XXX;`, I get this result (as you can see, each data is a string separated by ',' and ':'). Actually, there are lots of records and each value is too long not just 1 to 10 prefix.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                             VAL                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1:-132,2:-132,3:-94.442988,4:-94.696044,5:-99.627777,6:-100.732599,7:-101.758271,8:-102.175370,9:-134.134041,10:-344.344874 |
| 1:-983,2:-344,3:-434.34988,4:-34.696044,5:-87.634777,6:-99.3732599,7:-344.344271,8:-989.134340,9:-100.274701,10:-100.945874 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How to write a select query if I want to get the following result? I've gotten some hints from the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170080/4015877 . However I just can split the string to some parts.

There is two more problem to solve.

1. I want to use left value as a suffix for column name. (e.g. if the comma split value is `2:-132`, `2` is a suffix for column name and `-131` is a value).
2. I just want to extract some specific columns (e.g. like the following result `VAL_1, VAL_2, VAL_3, VAL_8, VAL_9, VAL_10` I don't want to get the rest).

### expected result

```
+-------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| VAL_1 | VAL_2 |  VAL_3  |   VAL_8  |   VAL_9  |  VAL_10  |
+-------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|  -132 |  -132 | -94.443 | -102.175 | -134.134 | -344.345 |
|  -983 |  -344 | -434.35 | -989.134 | -100.275 | -100.946 |
+-------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: This is almost impossible in SQLite. It would be a better idea to convert the data in a 'real' programming language.

Comment: It's not all that hard with a version that supports instr(). Just a little tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your version. This solution requires 3.7.15+ for instr().

```
sqlite> select sqlite_version();
```

```
sqlite_version()
----------------
3.8.2
```

```
create table tb_xxx ( val text );
insert into tb_xxx values ('1:-132,2:-132,3:-94.442988,4:-94.696044,5:-99.627777,6:-100.732599,7:-101.758271,8:-102.175370,9:-134.134041,10:-344.344874');
insert into tb_xxx values ('1:-983,2:-344,3:-434.34988,4:-34.696044,5:-87.634777,6:-99.3732599,7:-344.344271,8:-989.134340,9:-100.274701,10:-100.945874');
```

Look at the positions for the first "column". (The first value.)

```
select instr(VAL, '1:'), instr(VAL, ',2:') from tb_xxx;
1|7
1|7
```

The first value starts at `1 + length('1:')`, or 3, and ends at
7. That means it's four characters long. (It's `7 - 3` characters
long.)

```
sqlite>.headers on
sqlite>.mode column
sqlite>select substr(VAL, 3, 7 - 3) VAL_1 from tb_xxx;
```

```
VAL_1     
----------
-132      
-983
```

Replacing those literals with calls to instr(), and adjusting for
different values gives us this. Value 10 is different, because it
ends at the end of the string, not at the position of another matching
string.

```
select substr(VAL, 
              instr(VAL, '1:') + length('1:'), 
              instr(VAL, ',2:') - (instr(VAL, '1:') + length('1:'))
             ) VAL_1,
       substr(VAL, 
              instr(VAL, '2:') + length('2:'), 
              instr(VAL, ',3:') - (instr(VAL, '2:') + length('2:'))
             ) VAL_2,
       substr(VAL, 
              instr(VAL, '3:') + length('3:'), 
              instr(VAL, ',4:') - (instr(VAL, '3:') + length('3:'))
             ) VAL_3,
       substr(VAL, 
              instr(VAL, '8:') + length('8:'), 
              instr(VAL, ',9:') - (instr(VAL, '8:') + length('8:'))
             ) VAL_8,
       substr(VAL, 
              instr(VAL, '9:') + length('9:'), 
              instr(VAL, ',10:') - (instr(VAL, '9:') + length('9:'))
             ) VAL_9,
       substr(VAL,
              instr(VAL, '10:') + length('10:')
             ) VAL_10
from tb_xxx;
```

```
VAL_1       VAL_2       VAL_3       VAL_8        VAL_9        VAL_10     
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  -----------  -----------
-132        -132        -94.442988  -102.175370  -134.134041  -344.344874
-983        -344        -434.34988  -989.134340  -100.274701  -100.945874
```

I'll leave the rounding up to you.

There's no point in concatenating column aliases, because we know what
they're supposed to be when we write the query. And I don't think
that's possible in SQL anyway. It would be pretty simple in
application code, though.

This kind of parsing depends on well-formed input. For example, imagine your data had more keys, and keys out of order. When you use instr() to find the first occurrence of "1:", you match a different "key".

```
2:-132,11:-94.442988,1:-132, . . .
        ^^
```

It will find the end of "11:", not the "1:" you're actually looking for. On the one hand, you can partly dodge that problem by searching for ",1:". On the other hand, you can't find "2:" by searching for ",2:".

This is one reason DBAs never store data like yours. Another is that you can't apply sensible constraints, like "values for '1:' are always between 0 and -1000".