# SQLite query to get distinct columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a query where I need to check whether a value is not present in an array of strings returned by another nested query how can I do that,

For example I have to check whether,

```
1234 is present in [abc_1234,fgh_12345,ghi_5343]
```

Hence 1234 is present in string abc_1234 so I will not select 1234.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split FirstName and LastName in sqlite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155886/split-firstname-and-lastname-in-sqlite)

Comment: Just a side note: 1234 is also present in fgh_12345. If you don't consider this a match, then you should refine the rule that is to be applied.

Comment: Yes I will have to select 1234 if fgh_12345 is present as they don't exactly match

Comment: So what do you consider an exact match? Both strings contain the substring 1234 plus some other characters. Define exactly what is a match for you.

Comment: (BTW: It is usually a sign of poor database design when you have to evaluate substrings. Not always, of course. You can run a quick ad-hoc search on your items on '%socks%' so as to find socks, well knowing that you may not get all socks and you may even get some non-socks; and this doesn't mean your databse design is bad.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your request correctly. You have a query returning strings, e.g. 'abc_1234' and 'fgh_12345'. You have a table with values, e.g. '1234'. You want to select rows from the table where the value is not part of any of the strings of the existing query.

This is where the **anti-join pattern** comes into play. You outer-join the undesired rows, so all rows that found no partner are the desired ones:

```
select *
from mytable m
left join (<your query here>) q on instr(q.string, m.value) > 0
where q.string is null;
```

(Instead of `INSTR` you can also use `LIKE`: `on q.string like '%' || m.value || '%'`. It should not matter which of the string operations you choose.)