# Retrieve distinct tokens from SQLite3 column

Tags: sqlite

I want to add a new feature to my bookmarking utility, [Buku](https://github.com/jarun/Buku): retrieve all distinct tags.
Buku uses SQLite3.
A bookmark entry can have multiple tags separated by commas (,) in the same column `tags`.
Instead of retrieving the distinct values from column `tags` and then parsing them, is there any way I can tokenize the tags by comma and retrieve the distinct tags?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way would be to change the database structure.

Comment: Probably... but trying to figure out if there's any other way.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't function 'split' in sqlite3 database. Only [instr(X, Y)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) which returns position of only first occurrence. And there is function [substr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr). If number of tags in field is constant value you can create [complicated query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11170080/2940171) to split you string into rows and then select distinct from them.

So answer is no, don't try to do it by database engine. You should change structure or parse values after retrieving from database.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming!